# pylab plotting legend error

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I am trying to set a legend to plotted data in a graph.

But there seems to be an error in my code. 
I have the following error at the line where I'm setting a legend for the plot:

```
a.set_transform(self.get_transform())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_transform'
```

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np;
from pylab import *;

newData = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])
Action = 'abc'

line1 = 'class 0-' + Action
line2 = 'class 1 -others'

plot(newData[:,0],newData[:,1],'-')
figlegend( (line1, line2),('*', '-'),'upper right' )

hold(True)
plot(newData[:,1],newData[:,0],'*')
grid(True)
show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't assigned a in your code, set it to an object with the `set_transform` method and your code will work as expected.

For example

```
a = figlegend( (line1, line2),('*', '-'),'upper right' )
a.set_transform(self.get_transform())
```

See [Matplotlib Legend Demo](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo.html) for another example of legend usage.